# How to avoid page refresh in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[without refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAmOe.jpg)

When I click on any page link of the partial view, that related page should be displayed in the render body part without any page refresh. How can I do that ?

Comment: you can do ajax call for it.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? .NET4.6 or Core?

Comment: Realistically, it's too broad of a topic and sample code will only get you so far. Here's [documentation on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) to get you going. Doesn't matter what flavor of Asp.Net. Hth

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AJAX helper that is used in conjunction with unobtrusive ajax

[You can find more information at this page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-ajax-helper/)

- Install `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` NuGet package
- Include the script on _Layout `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>`
- You then use the HTML Helper with specific options

Code Sample

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View  All Student Info", "AllStudent", "Home", new AjaxOptions  
{  
  UpdateTargetId = "divAllStudent", 
  OnBegin = "fnOnBegin",  
  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
  HttpMethod = "GET",  
  LoadingElementId = "imgloader",  
  OnSuccess= "fnSuccess",  
  Confirm="Do you want to get all student info ?????"  
}, 
new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

- Then in the controller add a specific [GET] Route (WebAPI)

Code Sample

```
[HttpGet]  
public PartialViewResult AllStudent()  
{  
    using (TempEntities db = new TempEntities())  
    {  
        var objAllStudent = db.StudentInfoes.ToList();  
        return PartialView("AllStudent", objAllStudent);  
    }  
}
```

The options `UpdateTargetId` is the HTML ID container of where the AJAX result will put the result content. Usually you want to use Replace. You can use OnBegin and OnSuccess as Javascript methods that do things like show loaders, hide loaders, etc etc